# Complemented C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be unital separable commutative $C^*$ algebras, with $A\subset B$. Is it true that $A$ is complemented in $B$?

Comment: Do you assume that the identity in $A$ is also the identity in $B$?

Comment: Yes the Identity in A is also Identity in B

Answer (score 4):

No. The classical example is $A$ being the functions on $[0,1]$ that are right continuous, have left limits everywhere, and are left continuous except at dyadic rationals. $B$ is defined similarly but delete "dyadic". Both $A$ and $B$ are representations of the continuous functions on the Cantor set. The quotient $B/A$ is $c_0(R\setminus D)$, where $R$ is the set of rationals in $(0,1]$ and $D$ is the set of dyadic rationals in $(0,1]$. Check that the quotient map has no continuous linear lifting.

Comment: I should not have answered this question. This is not the first time that  @user44155 has been rude by asking a question, getting an answer, and not replying or accepting the answer.